# win32 API createFile function: converting to an LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code that gets the name of the file from a function, then passes it into createFile (expands to createFileA). An earlier question told me to use file.c_str() to convert the filename to an LPCTSTR which createFileA uses. However, this does not work, as the handle to the file is invalid every time createFileA is called. What am I doing wrong?

```
string file = getFilename();
HANDLE hf = CreateFile(file.c_str(),GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,(DWORD) 0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,(HANDLE) NULL);
if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
     MessageBox( hwnd,"CreateFile","Error", MB_OK);
   }
```

Comment: What error code does `GetLastError` return?

Comment: ERROR_INVALID_NAME
123 (0x7B)
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: If you run this under a debugger what does `file.c_str()` return?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that with the error: 
it returns 2012-6-1_17:10:40:475.bmp

Comment: Wow, I should have thought of this but colons are illegal in windows filenames. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question the problem is that the name you are providing contains a `:`.  This character is illegal for file names in windows and is the source of your problem.  Remove that character and the code should work fine

Answer (score 2):

If it compiles then .c_str() must be the correct type!

The most common reason for ERROR_INVALID_NAME  is an illegal character in the filename, an extra ":" or a tab or you are using a reserved filename.  Check the value of filename

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that if you used the following code

std::stringstream ss;
ss <<  "C:\filename.txt" <

Then do ss.str() to get to std::string.
Then if you do c_str() to pass to CreateFile

This will not work with CreateFile and its very hard to track the root cause
but its the "endl;", it got streamed into the buffer and so the path will be invalid

It will always report error 123 invalid file name

It also happens with the wide version.